# How to avoid redrawing evey objects at each frame in paper.js

Tags: javascript, paperjs

How to avoid redrawing eveything at each frame in paper.js?

I suppose I have to detach the frame event from the view `view.detach('frame');`, and then call draw manually every time I want to update something ?

This is very usefull to make drawing applications.

---

**EDIT**

[Here](https://c9.io/arthursw/oiio/workspace/drawings/index.html) is an example of what I want to avoid (click to toggle copies visibility):
the framerate decreases drastically when I show many other shapes (since everything is redrawn at each frame) but the copies could be drawn only on click and then let untouched (the framerate would be always high).

Just in case:
Symbols are not a solutions here, [this is](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bkhnD) maybe a better example of what I want to achieve. The trails are fading away since the canvas is not cleared at each frame, just darkened.

I found some infos about [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/paperjs/eCYwJyDvw18/cECDHVEyIUgJ), it seems redraw optimizations are not implemented yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I implemented the persistence request [here](https://github.com/arthursw/paper.js/tree/persistence), but I didn't pull it yet.

You can check two examples: the [tail effect](https://c9.io/arthursw/oiio/workspace/drawings/spacePersistence.html) and the [performance benchmark](https://c9.io/arthursw/oiio/workspace/drawings/index.html) (click to toggle visibility of modified clones, press 'space' to toggle persistence).
You can find the example code [here](https://c9.io/arthursw/oiio), under drawings.

Comment: Well, it's available here: https://github.com/arthursw/paper.js and you can have more details about the implementation on this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/paperjs/oTg73NhNUcM/EkY57pE2ZRAJ

Comment: So if I just copy your paper.js file into my app it just works with persistence out of the box?

Comment: Not a good fit for the type of app I am working with, although it sounded extremely promising..sigh..

Comment: What is your problem?